# ROW_NUMBER with PARTITION BY &ORDER BY performing very slow in hive (3million rows)

Tags: optimization, hive, bigdata, row-number

I have a Hive table with 50 columns and over 3 million records. The requirement is to fetch latest 200 records based on the date column, hence applied a row_number function. It worked really well initially when the number of records were under 100K, unfortunately it runs forever now. Is there any particular optimization technique that I can try ?
It is a partitioned table and this is the implementation for more details: ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date, rule_id, run_id ORDER BY load_date DESC) as rule_row_num from table

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow (SO). Here at SO we are a community trying to help each other. Please have a look at the "How do I ask a good question" (stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to better frame your question, and consider looking at the "Minimal, Reproducible Example" section as well (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you provide some code for what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the column you are partitioning by is skewed. You should `group by` that column and count the number of rows to confirm.

If skew actually happens, a general way of optimizing is to indroduce one stage ahead and try to partially aggregate and reduce the data.

As per your case, you can try this:

let's suppose your original SQL is like:

```
select * from (
    select 
        ca,
        cb,
        row_number() over(partition by ca order by cb desc) as rk1
    from my_table 
) tmp
where rk1 <=200;
```

The optimized version is gonna be sth like this:

```
with tt1 as(
    select 
        ca,
        cb,
        row_number() over(partition by ca, cast(rand()*20 as int) order by cb desc) as rk1 
    from my_table
)
select * from (
    select 
        ca,
        cb,
        row_number() over(partition by ca order by cb desc) as rk2
    from tt1
    where rk1 <= 200  
) tmp 
where rk2 <= 200;
```

When skew happens for the column `ca`, the second SQL is expected to be faster than the first one. More parallelism is added at the first stage by the `cast(rand()*20 as int)`. And after that, the predicate `where rk1 <= 200` is performed, significantly reducing data to be processed later.

Comment: It is a partitioned table and below is the implementation for more details:
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date, rule_id, run_id ORDER BY load_date DESC) as rule_row_num from table

Comment: @Sudhans Hi, please refer to the edited answer above, see if you find it kinda helpful :)

Comment: I have my select statement with filters based on all the columns used under PARTITION BY in my row_num function (function details in above comment). Do I really need to keep all these columns under PARTITION BY ?

Comment: @Sudhanshu Can you provide your specific SQL ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM table_t WHERE X_of_date=20191213 and rule_row_num<=200 and rule_id='ABC_XY_ID_123_GEAR' and run_id='some_id'